# ngShow/ngHide using a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button that I want to hide when the array `$scope.game.players.players` contains specific value.

```
button(ng-click="", ng-hide="ImPlaying()") Play
```

The function `ImPlaying()` checks the condition and return a boolean

```
$scope.ImPlaying = function(){
    $scope.game.players.playerExist($scope.user.socketID, function(exist){
        console.log(exist);
        return exist;
    });
}
```

`exist` change value but the button is always shown

But when I replace the function `$scope.game.players.playerExist()` by its code everything works as expected.

```
$scope.ImPlaying = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.game.players.players.length; i++) {
        if($scope.game.players.players[i]){
            if($scope.game.players.players[i].socketID == $scope.user.socketID){
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
    return false;
}
```

What's wrong with the first function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing return statement in ImPlaying function

```
$scope.ImPlaying = function(){
    return $scope.game.players.playerExist($scope.user.socketID, function(exist){
        console.log(exist);
        return exist;
    });
}
```